# Python + OpenCV - Copying an image to some directory

Tags: python, opencv, copy

I would like to **copy** some images to some directory, rather than `cv2.imwrite` the images. The reason is that when I use `cv2.imwrite` in OpenCV, I get images that are larger than the original ones, apart from that I can see that some images are being rotated.

Would that be possible in Python + OpenCV, since I don't want any operation to be made on the original image, which `cv2.imwrite` seems to be doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need opencv to do this. You can use the [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) library.

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile('path/to/1.jpg', 'new/path/to/1.jpg')
```

Note that the destination path must specify the filename too. If you don't want this, you can use `shutil.copy2` which lets you specify a directory as the destination.

```
shutil.copy2('path/to/1.jpg', 'new/path/to/dir')
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Yes, my destination is a directory. I used "copy". Does that differ from using "copy2"?

Comment: The only difference is that the `atime` and `mtime` of a file are not changed (with copy2). Besides that, there is no difference.

Comment: When I use "copy2" I get "NameError: name 'copy2' is not defined", provided that I'm doing "import shutil"

Comment: @Simplicity Here's the docs for copy2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2

Comment: For "copy2" I had to do the following: "from shutil import copy2" :-)

Comment: Thanks for your kind support, appreciate it!

Comment: @Simplicity Ah, yep. Won't work unless you either do that, or `import shutil; shutil.copy2(.., ..)`. No problem, cheers.